# Flask is there a way to scramble/mask/hash variable urls?

Tags: python, flask

I want to scramble or mask my variable urls so that people can't see/know private information.

For example, if I have a route,

```
@app.route('/customer/<custid>')
def display(custid):
    # do stuff
    return render_template('custpage.html' foo=foo)
```

`custid=1` would be `~/customer/1/`

Now is there a way to hash the customer id in the url so that 
`custid=1` would be `~/customer/somehash/`?

Comment: Wouldn't that just mean the hash is just as sensitive as the id?

Comment: First of all, security through obscurity is rarely a good idea. Second, sure, `custid` can be a hash but then you need to have somewhere a `hash(custid) => custid` map so that you can recover the actual customer ID when being presented a hash.

Comment: Why do you want to hide the id?

Comment: @Roman the id's in my case are from fpds.gov so they are duns numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a similar approach as if you would create a referral URL.

Make a new column, where you will save a unique string, which can identify this user. Instead of using the ID in all URL's, you will use the unique string.

You can ofcourse make a hash out of the id and save it there or just use a random function to create a long string.

If you want to work with hashes (but that is not necessary):

```
import hashlib
hash_object = hashlib.sha256(b"user-id-" + str.encode(str(current_user.id)))
```

You could of course just generate a random code, which has a certain length. With length 15+ the chance to generate the same code is almost 0. And the unique attribute of the column will prevent the super rare case where an identical code would be generated.

```
def get_promo_code(num_chars):
    code_chars = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    code = ''
    for i in range(0, num_chars):
        slice_start = random.randint(0, len(code_chars) - 1)
        code += code_chars[slice_start: slice_start + 1]
    return code
```

Call it:

```
get_promo_code(15)
```